# Java HttpURLConnection - sending password form posts doesn't work

Tags: java, html, post

There is a website from which I want to access the data in my Java program. When opening the site in a browser, instead of the content I want to see, there is a text field for the password and a button for submitting it. After typing in the correct password and pressing the submit button, I can see the content. The URL is still the same. Normally I can get the html data using code like this:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://wordpress.***.***/***/***/***/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Of course this won't print out the data I want to access. The interesting part is probably this one:

```
    <form action="https://wordpress.***.***/***/wp-login.php?action=postpass" class="post-password-form" method="post">
<p>Some text:</p>
<p><label for="pwbox-526">Passwort: <input name="post_password" id="pwbox-526" type="password" size="20" /></label> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Absenden" /></p>
</form>
```

After researching a bit about sending form posts in Java, I came up with this code, though now it doesn't print anything:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://wordpress.***.***/***/wp-login.php?action=postpass");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        String postData = "post_password=*******&Submit=Absenden";

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", postData.length() + "");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.connect();

        var out = connection.getOutputStream();
        out.write(URLEncoder.encode(postData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

[This is what the network panel looks like in the Microsoft Edge Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAYE6.png)

Does anyone have a solution? This is the first time I'm working with networks in a Java project. I need it for an android app btw.